# Black background of WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I created simple window and applied style to it. Now, when I run application background is black:
[image]

In XAML it looks normal:
[image]

What is causing this?

Here is XAML code:

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                        <Grid Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                            <StatusBar Name="statusBar1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <Grid>
        <Grid Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,0,557,622" Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="466">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Label4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" MinHeight="16" MinWidth="97" Name="xResourceLabel4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <Label Content="Label1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" MinHeight="16" MinWidth="98" Name="xResourceLabel1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <Label Content="Label2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" MinHeight="16" MinWidth="114" Name="xResourceLabel2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <Label Content="Label3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,3,0" MinHeight="16" MinWidth="80" Name="xResourceLabel3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <TextBox Background="#FFFFFF99" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="120,0,189,0" MinHeight="23" MinWidth="157" Name="tbREGNR" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <TextBox Background="#FFFFFF99" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,189,0" MinHeight="23" MinWidth="157" Name="tbFaFabnr" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <ComboBox Background="#FFFFFF99" DisplayMemberPath="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,189,0" MinHeight="24" MinWidth="157" Name="cb" SelectedValuePath="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <TextBox Background="#FFFF99CC" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,175,0" MinHeight="23" MinWidth="171" Name="tbComp" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                        <StatusBar Name="statusBar1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
                        </Grid>
```

Because you are overriding the default template for the Window you are taking away the style effects (of which one is background = black on the root grid)

see above, i've put it in the template and it should now work (Background="White")

Below is the default template for a window (Taken From Blend)

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WindowTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid>
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </AdornerDecorator>
                <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsTabStop="false" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
                    <Condition Property="WindowState" Value="Normal"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WindowResizeGrip" Value="Visible"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="WindowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplateKey}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: That solved Grid background, but if I set window background to White, it is still black!

Comment: This line looks interesting '<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>' but what to do with it, schould I override or something?

Comment: That is where it sets the background of your window, but because your LayoutRoot Grid is set to stretch you should not see any background of your window whatsover

Comment: This answer is useful but does that mean that I have to set background of every element to white? And what if I want some space between two grids, for example? That space will always be black.

Comment: With regards to: "That solved Grid background, but if I set window background to White, it is still black!" When you set the window background it is now completely hidden from you by your LayoutRoot Grid defined in your template

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is black only if I don't set it to Stretch. Marking as answer...

Answer (score 0):

Based on TBohnen.jnr's answer, the actual correct answer would be do it as the default window template and add `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` to the top-level child element of the `ControlTemplate`. In the default template it is a `Border`, whereas in your case it's the `Grid`:

```
<Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
```